# Почему следующий код не приводит к сегфолту?

Tags: c, указатели, malloc

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    unsigned char (*b)[5];

    b = malloc( 5 );

    for ( ; i < 100 ; i++ ) {

        *(b+i)[0] = 192;
        *(b+i)[1] = 168;
        *(b+i)[2] = 0;
        *(b+i)[3] = 1+i;

        printf( "%d.%d.%d.%d\n", *(b+i)[0], *(b+i)[1], *(b+i)[2], *(b+i)[3] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

В моем понимании функция malloc() выделяет только 5 байт , и как минимум на 6-м шаге цикла ( i == 5 ) указатель должен выйти за рамки отведенной процессу памяти, почему этого не происходит?

Собираю с помощью gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)

Comment: Знаете что такое undefined behaviour? Он таки undefined.

Comment: Потому что размер страницы памяти 4096 байт (по умолчанию так сказать "квант" памяти), и fail может наступить только если следущей страницы не сделано allocate, поэтому даже переходя за грань 4096 fail может быть а может и не быть. Пока программа маленькая такие трюки могут заканчиваться ничем, а при большой программе можно получить глюки которые очень сложно отловить.

Comment: Если у вас стоит задача получить seg-fail  то можно пробовать читать/писать с шагом 4096 байт.

Comment: Задача как-раз таки - не наткнутся при использовании бОльших структур=) Спасибо Вам за разъяснения, действительно - при увеличении размера массива до [4096] падение происходит на 30-м шаге

Comment: лучше освоить valgrind и вылавливать таких жуков.

Comment: Вы очень ошибаетесь в выводах. Нельзя выходить за рамки выделеной памяти массива однозначно. если sfail не произошёл -  вы можете записать в память соседнего обьекта - и долго не понимать почему программа даёт странный баг (обьекты будут вдруг равны странным значениям). Ещё хуже - если вы повредите структуру памяти при malloc то у вас ф-кции памяти "вдруг" перестанут работать по "непонятной" причине, которую возможно найдёте не скоро.

Comment: Напротив, Вы прояснили поведение кода, которое для меня поначалу оказалось неожиданным. "Магическая" составляющая отпала, и все стало на свои места - нужна память - инициализируй её.
Еще раз благодарю.

Comment: Не *инициализируй*,  а *выдели и работай с ней*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Из комментария пользователя [@nick_n_a](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/17974/nick-n-a):*

Потому что размер страницы памяти 4096 байт (по умолчанию, так сказать «квант» памяти), и fail может наступить только если для следущей страницы не сделано allocate. Поэтому даже переходя за грань 4096 fail может быть а может и не быть. Пока программа маленькая такие трюки могут заканчиваться ничем, а при большой программе можно получить глюки, которые очень сложно отловить.

Если у вас стоит задача получить seg-fail, то можно пробовать читать/писать с шагом 4096 байт.

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что `malloc` выделяет память из *кучи* — заранее выделенного диапазона страниц памяти. В куче лежат вперемешку все выделенные `malloc`-ом фрагменты, плюс служебные данные самой кучи.

Соответственно, когда вы пытаетесь обратиться (прочитать или записать) за пределами выделенного вам диапазона памяти, вы **всё ещё остаётесь в диапазоне памяти для кучи** (потому падения и не происходит). Однако вы залезаете:

- либо **в область, запрошенную другой частью вашей программы** (тогда падение произойдёт при некорректной интерпретации тех данных),
- либо **в служебные структуры** (тогда падение произойдёт при очередном запросе/освобождении блока кучи).